# How to clear a column value in quotes table on log in

Tags: event-observer, login, shopping-cart, quote, customer-session

I want to be able to clear a custom column like this as soon as I login and I find that a particular SKU is in the cart.:

```
$quote -> setcolumn('');
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try creating an observer for `customer_login`

In config.xml

```
 .....
<customer_login>
    <observers>
        <yourobservername>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>yourmodule/path_to_class</class>
            <method>customerLogin</method>
        </yourobservername>
    </observers>
</customer_login>
```

In Observer.php

```
class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        //$customer = $observer->getCustomer();
       $updateCart = false
       $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
       $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
       foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
           if($sku == $item->getSku()){
              $item->setcolumn('');
              $updateCart = true;
           }
       }

       if(updateCart){
           $quote$quote->getCart()->save();
       }

    }
}
```

See [Magento - remove one quantity from cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397952/magento-remove-one-quantity-from-cart)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$_NULL = new Zend_Db_Expr("NULL");
$quote -> setcolumn($_NULL);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: What are you supposed to do with this answer? And who ever down voted, can I know the reason?